Hybrid PQC in TLS 1.3 and the Expand-Extract Process
In the hybrid PQC TLS 1.3 RFC, we have he following figure

What is the significance of showing "Derive-Secret(...)" three times, and then two times and then  four times? Is this just saying that you extract multiple secrets from the process in order to generate the Master Secret or something else? Can someone explain this figure?
Also, if we look at the figure for the concatenated X25519+Kyber768 (ML-KEM), I assume that the two secrets shown are then fed into this extract-expand process. Is this correct?
In this process, if X25519 is broken, we do not care because the loss of 50% of the concatenated secret does not affect the derived key. Is this correct?
The same can be said if Kyber is broken, but X25519 is not. Is this understanding correct?


What is the significance of showing "Derive-Secret(...)" three times, and then two times and then four times? Is this just saying that you extract multiple secrets from the process in order to generate the Master Secret or something else? Can someone explain this figure?

It's just showing how the concatenated shared secret would fit in the existing TLS 1.3 key derivation logic (TLDR; it just fits in exactly where we previously put the (EC)DHE shared secret).
If you contrast this diagram with the derivation diagram from RFC 8446 (TLS 1.3), section 7.1, you'll see that it is precisely the same (with the three derived secrets before we insert the (EC)DHE or hybrid shared secret, and then two and then four afterwards.  The only change they are making is changing what is presented to the key derivation logic as the 'shared secret between the two sides'.
In other words, they are proposing a minimal change to the existing protocol.

In this process, if X25519 is broken, we do not care because the loss of 50% of the concatenated secret does not affect the derived key. Is this correct?

Well, I wouldn't put it that way.  Instead, what we do is include a value (from ML-KEM) they the attacker does not know - because the TLS 1.3 shared secret processing is strong, the attacker needs to guess all the bits to recover the derived keys (which is what he cares about) and with 256 unknown bits, that is infeasible.

The same can be said if Kyber is broken, but X25519 is not. Is this understanding correct?

Yes, by the same logic - in that case, there are 256 unknown bits from the X25519 (actually, 252 because of the X25519 group order, but that's not important) and recovering those is also infeasible (as long as X25519 is unbroken).


if you want formal proof that the derived keys from concatenated secrets will be secure even if one gets broken can be found https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/903.pdf specifically "dualPRF"

